# Mechanical computing hardware for a future Venusian rover? How does it work?

Tags: venus, lander, temperature, high-pressure-environment

I don't know why Gizmodo says [NASA's Latest Venus Probe Concept Looks Like a Tim Burton Creation](http://gizmodo.com/nasas-latest-venus-probe-concept-looks-like-a-tim-burto-1798501354), because it looks far more like a [Theo Jansen creation](http://www.strandbeest.com/)! Compare videos below as well.

I can understand looking into wind to power strictly mechanical instead of electromechanical locomotion, but I don't see how meaningful computing could be done mechanically. Roughly, what kind of mechanical computing hardware is being considered for a future Venusian rover? Is it like 1 FLOP and 1 kilobit, or something small and dense or even [MEMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems)-like?

I'm interested because the [10,000 year satellite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8YMx.jpg) could really benefit from non-electronic computers to survive in space that long!

See also NASA's [Automaton Rover for Extreme Environments (AREE)](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/spacetech/niac/2017_Phase_I_Phase_II/Automaton_Rover_Extreme_Environments).

[image]

---

Comment: I'd be reasonably sure that AREE will contain a more or less conventional, electronic microprocessor. Since these can be made so tiny and low-power nowadays, it wouldn't be a big problem to keep it at sufficiently low temperature.

Comment: A rover without an electronic transmitter and receiver would be useless anyway. There is no pure mechanic camera for navigation. If you don't get any results from the rover with a mechanic computer, you will never know what happens to the rover.

Comment: @Uwe the world is filled with organisms that don't make use of vision to navigate through and learn about their environment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindness_in_animals#Totally_blind_species

Comment: What is the use of a venusian rover without vision but tactile sensors and without any data transmission to Earth? We should get some results but there is no mechanical data transmission to Earth.

Comment: @Uwe I don't understand why not having a camera means there will be no data transmission to Earth or that tactile sensors are the only other possible sensor.

Comment: If you use mechanic computation instead of electronic computation due to the high temperature of Venus, you can't use electronic data transmission. Is there any kind of non electronic wireless mechanical data transmission applicable to Venus? If there is a high temperature electronic data transmission, there should be a high temperature electronic computation too.

Comment: @Uwe there are in fact real examples of this, if you post a simple question asking if some kind of "non electronic wireless mechanical data transmission" system is possible in space, and if it could be adapted to work on Venus I think we can have some real answers. They certainly are not as practical and some kind of high-temperature electronics and high-temperature optimized RTG-powered cooled electronics using conventional communications.

Comment: Something completely different! What if a main electronic computer was in orbit around Venus & linked to a surface rover by a "skytrain" system of satellites"? Yes, it would be expensive, but ... just a thought. A mechanical computer might be heavy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't underestimate what you can do with mechanical components. In the **18**40s, Charles Babbage worked on a programmable general-purpose computer (the [Analytical Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Engine)). Sadly, it was never completed, although the idea is sound. An earlier design of his, the [Difference Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine) (which was not Turing-complete), was built in the 1990s.

That said, the [AREE study](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/niac_2016_phasei_saunder_aree_tagged.pdf) hasn't advanced to the point of designing hardware. From page 19, the study summarizes the possible solutions (mechanical, pneumatics/fluidics, vacuum tubes and other electronics), then shows some possible implementations for elements like power storage, and navigation using a method for obstacle avoidance that does not need computation.

> While Phase 1 demonstrated feasibility, a number of areas remain that require further refinement and demonstration to establish concept credibility. Continued work on a Venus rover concept that does not require yet to be developed technologies with unknown costs and timescales significantly changes the conversation with regards to Venus missions and achievable science.

Comment: I think this is absolutely fascinating! Thank you for the links, I'll take a look :-)

Comment: Not only Babbage worked on a computer with mechanical components, Konrad Zuse's first Z1 used a lot of mechanics too. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z1_(computer) But both Babbage and Zuse had problems with insufficient mechanical precision.

Comment: Thats general-purpose computing. But for specific applications its sometimes possible to represent problems in very small mechanical solutions. Battleships were able to input their course, speed, and the bearing, distance and estimated heading of an aircraft or enemy ship, and have just a few gears output the heading and barrel angle required to lead and successfully hit the target. Complex functions can be encoded as a slot or groove on a single rotating disk, for example (as complex as audio wave forms, eg. vinyl. Compare that to the complexity of electronic reproduction of audio.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't a computer as the term is usually understood today, and it certainly isn't using morse code.

What the system is actually doing is taking the output of an instrument, probably a low voltage electrical signal, amplifying it to something mechanically usable, and converting it into rotation of the four disks on top of the rover (with 4 positions each, it's the equivalent of an 8 bit signal).

The value shown on those disks can be seen from an orbiter or high altitude baloon that can use conventional computers for all the more complex tasks.

Physically, the 'computer' part would be a bunch of gears that move the disks.

As shown in the previous answers, you can calculate a surprising with such systems, but due to weight concerns the complexity would probably be kept to a minimum - for example using relative positioning of the disks rather than resetting to an absolute value because the orbiter can easily subtract the previous value with no weight penalty.

Comment: But how do you amplify a low voltage electric signal without electronics to something mechanically usable? The question was about mechanical computing hardware, therefore no electronic amplifiers.

Comment: @Uwe True, that part can't be just gears. However, it is more part of the instrument than the computer (you probably can't make a camera purely mechanical anyway), and it can use heavy electrical components rather than easily melted silicon chips.

Comment: @QuentinClarkson Making a purely mechanical camera isn't that difficult if you've got [nearly two centuries of experience making them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_from_the_Window_at_Le_Gras), but I suppose getting the image back to Earth might pose a bit of a challenge.

Comment: @8bittree A purely mechanical camera may sustain high temperatures, but you need a photographic film or plate that does not melt.

Comment: @8bittree That isn't mechanical, it's a chemical process - and the important part is having a way to transmit the image (or other data using similar sensors, like measuring the exact color flame produced when a sample is heated). Retrieving film capsules has been done from LEO, but isn't really practical for all the data from a year long mission.

Comment: Is [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore) a better analogy than Morse code for the disc communication? Doesn't Venus have fairly opaque clouds? It would have to be viewed by something that can dip below the clouds to see it then go back above them where conditions are friendlier and there is more sunlight to recharge batteries perhaps, like a solar plane maybe.

Comment: @uhoh Yes, that's a much closer analogy. The image in the gizmodo article labels the disks as radar targets - the clouds are only opaque if you are limited to visible light.

Comment: @QuentinClarkson Ah, so you didn't just mean non-electronic. My first thought was actually circuit breakers rather than film. Let the light shine on and heat pairs of two different metal strips and as the metals expand at different rates, the bonded pair would bend. Definitely difficult to make practical and possibly too much of a thermal process. Well we know that light applies pressure, so in theory we could still make a purely mechanical camera. Though I'm doubtful it would work well outside of a vacuum. And in both of these cases, there's still the issue of getting the image back.

Comment: @8bittree the problem with sensors like that is sensitivity - if you put enough load on it to physically move anything, it won't be able to respond to the small changes you want to measure.

Answer (score 3):

Also don't forget that we don't have to do everything digitally.  [Analog computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer) were common until fading out in the 60's and 70's, but can be useful in some areas.

Comment: That's a good point; I've assumed the mechanical computers were digital but that was just a reflex, thanks! But I think this is more of a comment than an actual stackexchange answer; I've asked about a particular NASA plan, "...how does it work?" not just ideas of what might work.

Comment: But the analog computers of  the 60's and 70's were to more than 90 % fully semiconductor electronic. In the 40's and 50's there were also electronic anlog computers equipped with vacuum tubes.

Comment: You can do a lot with pure analog mechanical designs.  EX the fire control systems on battleships.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1i-dnAH9Y4

Answer (score 3):

Nanomechanical computers are much more energy efficient then electric microchips. They can deal with a lot of electromagnetic noise, and really big temperature differences. Their memory is more resistant, and they are compact. They have a lower clock rate, but because they release a small fraction of electric computers, they can outperform electric computers within the same volume.

Nanomechanical computers are still being worked on, and are the next logical step for general computing. How the venus mechanical rover will probably work has already been answered, but this will allow far more complex rovers for venus in the future.

For further reading see this excellent summary [Two Types of Mechanical Reversible Logic](https://www.zyvex.com/nanotech/mechano.html) by Ralph C. Merkle (1990) at [Xerox PARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARC_(company))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! While I don't doubt your assertions, in SE we need to support our answers with sources, otherwise it's impossible for present and future readers to judge the veracity of any given answer. Can you cite a source that supports this comparison? *Thanks!*

Comment: This link http://www.zyvex.com/nanotech/mechano.html is one of many that goes indepth about the possibilities of nanomechanical reversible logic. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thanks, what a cool link! I've added your reference back into your answer post; in Stack Exchange comments should be considered temporary, they can potentially be deleted at any time. So anything important for an answer should be added to the answer itself. If there's any way to support "much more energy efficient" and "they can outperform" as factually correct, please add those links as well. If there's something in Merkle 1990 that does so, please add a short quote from it. It's quite long and we can't expect each future reader to go looking through the whole thing. *Thanks!*